# read multi word text from command line

Tags: git, shell, command-line, stdin

When I'm writing a shell script like this:

```
echo -n 'Enter description of new version: ';

read desc;

git commit -m $desc;
```

and when I'm entering multi word description, then it is taking only one word into $desc
and giving me errors as:

```
Enter description of new version: hope it works
error: pathspec 'it' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'works'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
fatal: too many params
```

and sometimes it is giving like:

```
Enter description of new version: final check
error: pathspec 'check'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
fatal: Failed to resolve 'check'' as a valid ref.
Everything up-to-date
```

What is the problem with my script?

Please suggest the cause and solution to read multi word description from command-line into the variable $desc

I've tried using:

```
echo -n 'Enter description of new version: ';

read text;

desc="'"$text"'";

git commit -m $desc;
```

But no use.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I tried using `git commit -m '$desc'` and also `git commit -m '"'$desc'"'` But it didn't work, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote:

```
git commit -m "$desc"
```

The difference is the one between:

```
git commit -m hope it works
```

and

```
git commit -m "hope it works"
```

The first tries to commit the files `it` and `works` with the message `hope`, while the latter commits the index with the message `hope it works`.

Comment: Ya for that purpose, I used single quotes i.e., ` git commit -m '$desc' ` 

Also i tried using `git commit -m '"'$desc'"'`

But it didn't work, why?

Comment: Parameters are not expanded inside single quotes. In the second case, you aren't quoting `$desc`, so it still expands into separate words before the shell even looks the two literal double-quotes (which are each separately quoted by single quotes).